# JS Loop based on number of data in Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I want to make a loop in JS that creates a div for every "id" on my Array. For example, I have the following:

```
var Boletins =
{
    id:1, items:
    [
        {
            "#": "1",
            "Data": "19 a 25 de Março de 2021",
            "Região": "região de Trás-Os-Montes e Alto Douro",
            "Niveis": "muito elevados",
            "PoleneArvore": "cipreste, pinheiro",
            "PoleneErva": "urtiga, gramíneas"
        }],
    id:2, items:
        [
            {
                "#": "10",
                "Data": "26 de Março a 1 de Abril de 2021",
                "Região": "região de Trás-Os-Montes e Alto Douro",
                "Niveis": "muito elevados",
                "PoleneArvore": "plátano, cipreste, pinheiro, carvalhos"
            }
        ]
}
```

Based on the id, I want to make a loop that creates a Div in HTML for each entry of "id" present on the array. In my code it reaches id:14 but I only pasted until id:2.
This is my code to create the divs:

```
htmlText += '<div class="divBoletim">';    
htmlText += '<p>Created Div</p>';             
htmlText += '</div>'; 
$('body').append(htmlText);
```

I'm just not understanding how I would make a loop for each id entry. Thanks in advance for those who help.

Comment: Your structure is not valid. You can not have same keys in same array level

Comment: @Justinas Ok, so what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Wrap each `id` and `items` to it's own object: `Boletins = [{id: .., items: []}, {id: , items: []}...]`

Comment: @Justinas Ok, fixing it now, thanks! But after that, how can I loop it then?

Comment: If there's only going to be one object in the `items` array don't use an array just have the object as the value of `items`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With js you cannot use that structure, for the object `Boletins`, as for every object you can use just one attribute with name `id` and one attribute with the name `items`. If you use the structure you showed us in your code the object `Boletins` will contain just an attribute `id` (with value 2) and an attribute `items`. To loop as you'd like you need to use an array:

```js
const boletins = [{
 id: 1,
 data: '19 a 25 de Março de 2021',
 ...
}, {
 id: 2,
 data: '...',
 ...
}];
```

Once you've defined the array with this code you can have a `for` loop:

```js
for (let i=0; i<boletins.length; i++) {
  const item = boletins[i];
  console.log(item.data); // first way to get the info you need
  console.log(item['data']); // second way
  // do something
}
```

or using a `forEach` loop:

```js
boletins.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item.data);
  console.log(item['data']);
  // do something.
});
```

You can access also directly to the elements by using:

```js
const firstData = boletins[0].data;
const secondPoleneErva = boletins[1]['PoleneErva'];
```

I suggest you to use [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for your variable names.

Comment: Thanks! Working now. Just something more, how can I access for example, the value of "Data" inside the items of id:1 ?

Comment: I've modified my answer to explain better how to use the arrays and the objects in js. If this is clear enough consider to click the grey check icon near my answer.